# From Windows, how to extract certain files from .sparsebundle Time Machine backup?

Tags: windows, macos

I have a Windows 10 system and don’t have access to a Mac any more, but I need to extract certain files from a .sparesbundle Time Machine backup image that was created on a Mac. I've tried MacDrive soft, but it just didn't work. I tried HFS+ app - it just hangs when I choose the `.sparsebundle` file.

Is there any way to extract my files from this backup on a Windows 10 machine?

Comment: [Recover certain files from Time machine from previous Mac](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/158645)

Comment: bro, if i had a mac, i wouldn't ask a question here :)

Comment: Ah. Missed the Window 10 reference :(

Comment: related, though maybe to old to be considered a dupe - https://superuser.com/questions/61778/mount-mac-disk-image-and-sparse-bundle-on-windows-or-linux

Answer (score 0):

[HFS Explorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/) supports sparsebundle you should be able to extract the files with it